# Guake terminal showing up wrong in Unity

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, unity, guake

It seems Guake terminal is not aware of the Unity sidebar being hidden. Even when the sidebar is hidden, it still shows with a left offset that is based on the width of the sidebar.

Additionally, the width of the terminal is not decreased by the width of the left offset, which causes the terminal to appear on my second monitor as well.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Guake terminal showing up incorrectly in Unity]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a work-around, you can adjust the Guake terminal width to less then 100% of the screen width.

1. Make a backup of `/usr/lib/guake/guake.py` for Ubuntu 12.04 and for Ubuntu 12.10 and newer, backup `/usr/bin/guake` file.
2. Open a terminal and run the following command:

   For Ubuntu 12.04:

   ```
   sudo -i
   gedit /usr/lib/guake/guake.py
   exit
   ```

   For Ubuntu 12.10 (or newer) Guake versions, use the following command instead:

   ```
   sudo -i
   gedit /usr/bin/guake
   exit
   ```
3. Then scroll down to somewhere around line 780-820 which says `width = 100` - this is how it looks like:

   ```
   screen = self.window.get_screen()
   height = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_height'))
   width = 100
   halignment = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_halignment'))
   ```

   And modify the width value (percentage) to whatever you want. Save the file, restart Guake and that's it.

---

Reference: [WepUp8 Article](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/how-to-adjust-guake-terminal-width.html)

Comment: Thanks! Note in Ubuntu 12.10 it is: `gksu gedit /usr/bin/guake`

Comment: Pardon me but how do I restart guake? `exit`ing and reopening guake with <kbd>F12</kbd> did not work (the setting did not change). Is there an option other than `kill`ing the guake process?

Comment: Right click it and select Quit.

Answer (score 3):

I had another problem. The first few lines of guake were hidden by the Unity top panel. This can be solved changing the variable "window_rect.y" in line 835 (Natty) from 0 to 30, as shown below.

window_rect.y = 30

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It helped me after switching from Ubuntu with Unity to XUbuntu with XFCE desktop.

Comment: You helped me a lot! I just upgraded to Raring and Guake was showing lower than it should. Changing that setting solved my problem!

Answer (score 3):

In 12.04, default configuration with side bar always shown, the problem with guake is that the right side of the terminal output is hidden. It seems that is not aware of the real visible size available. 
Using Alin Andrei suggestion with

```
width = 95
```

I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a better workaround, or rather, a fix.

Open `/usr/lib/guake/guake.py` and scroll to line 786 containing:

```
self.window.move(window_rect.x, window_rect.y)
```

Move it under this line, no 788:

```
self.window.show_all()
```

All works as expected after a restart of Guake - at least for me up to now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go and fix Guake's code! `:)`

To be more serious, we are working on the positioning and sizing issues.

Comment: Someone should make a Guake lens so it's all nice and integrated!

Comment: @Jorge: hmmm so it's possible to embed applications into lenses?

Comment: @Alin We could probably embed a VTE widget into a lens. If anyone is interested in doing this work have them get ahold of me (link in my profile) and I'll point them towards the right Unity developer.

Answer (score 0):

Guake 0.4.4 && Ubuntu 12.04

Edit in file:

```
gksu gedit /usr/bin/guake
```

Line 826:

```
width = VALUE
```

Save file and **restart** Guake!

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple hack.

1. Open guake.
2. Open all the workspaces (<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).
3. Drag guake terminal from one screen to another.
4. Open the desired screen.

This works for me always on Ubuntu 13.10. To adjust the size, just close and open guake again by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.